# How to upload file to Azure blob but with different filename in c#?

Tags: c#, azure, upload, blob

I have a file named as MyFile_1.ext.
I want to upload the file to Azure blob, but with file name MyFile_2.ext

Is there any way to do that in c#?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show some source code on how you perform this action?

Comment: Actually I have not tried anything yet. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the example from the Microsoft Docs ([Upload blobs to a container](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet#upload-blobs-to-a-container)):

```
// Create a local file in the ./data/ directory for uploading and downloading
string localPath = "./data/";
string fileName = "quickstart" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".txt";
string localFilePath = Path.Combine(localPath, fileName);

// Write text to the file
await File.WriteAllTextAsync(localFilePath, "Hello, World!");

// Get a reference to a blob
BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);

Console.WriteLine("Uploading to Blob storage as blob:\n\t {0}\n", blobClient.Uri);

// Open the file and upload its data
using FileStream uploadFileStream = File.OpenRead(localFilePath);
await blobClient.UploadAsync(uploadFileStream);
uploadFileStream.Close();
```

The `GetBlobClient` method takes the desired blob file name as a parameter. So all you have to do is to pass it here...

Comment: You should let him know the sample is using v12 storage sdk, it's quite different from the previous version.

Comment: Good point. However, It is the latest version and the docs already tags v11 with legacy :D